# Left div with fixed width and right div with fluid width

Tags: html, css

I have a situation where I **cannot change the HTML** and everything has to be done with CSS.**** In the image below you can see there are text on either side of the input box. I need to have all text to be on left side. The span containing the text has a fixed width of 30 pixels. And I need the input box to have a fluid width so that it will fill the rest of the container. I just added a background color to the first container for illustration purposes.

```
<div class="input-group input-prepend">
    <input name="monthlyBudget" class="form-control" placeholder="0" required="" data-bind="number, live: monthlyBudget" data-parsley-min="50" data-parsley-max="5000" data-parsley-validation-threshold="1" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" data-parsley-errors-container="#affordabilityCalErrorBudget" type="text">
    <span class="input-group-addon add-on">$</span>
</div>
```

Entire HTML for the form:

```
<form class="calculators-form-inputs no-submit" id="form-calculator-affordability" name="calculator-affordability" data-parsley-validate="">
        <div class="calculators-info-text">
            <h2>How Much Car Can I Afford?</h2>
            <p>Great question. Fill in the boxes below to help with the answer and determine what price you can afford to pay for a car.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="calculators-form-field credit-amount">
            <div class="calculators-labels">
                <label>Your monthly budget                  <i class="label-tooltip icon-info-sign glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip"></i>
                    <a class="calculators-helper-link" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#budgetCalModal">(Help me)</a>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="calculators-sliders">
                <input type="range" value="0" min="50" max="5000" step="50" tabindex="-1" data-bind="value: monthlyBudget">
            </div>
            <div class="calculators-inputs">
                <div class="input-group input-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-addon add-on">$</span>
                    <input name="monthlyBudget" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="0" required="" data-bind="number, live: monthlyBudget" data-parsley-min="50" data-parsley-max="5000" data-parsley-validation-threshold="1" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" data-parsley-errors-container="#affordabilityCalErrorBudget">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="calculators-inputs-error" id="affordabilityCalErrorBudget"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="calculators-form-field credit-term">
            <div class="calculators-labels">
                <label>Loan term<i class="label-tooltip icon-info-sign glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip"></i>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="calculators-sliders">
                <input type="range" value="0" min="12" max="84" step="12" tabindex="-1" data-bind="value: loanTerm">
            </div>
            <div class="calculators-inputs">
                <div class="input-group input-append">
                    <input name="loanTerm" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="0" required="" data-bind="number, live: loanTerm" data-parsley-min="12" data-parsley-max="84" data-parsley-type="digits" data-parsley-validation-threshold="1" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" data-parsley-pattern="^(12|24|36|48|60|72|84)$" data-parsley-errors-container="#affordabilityCalErrorTerm">
                    <span class="input-group-addon add-on">mo</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="calculators-inputs-error" id="affordabilityCalErrorTerm"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="calculators-form-field credit-apr">
            <div class="calculators-labels">
                <label>APR*<i class="label-tooltip icon-info-sign glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip"></i>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="calculators-sliders">
                <input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="30" step="0.1" tabindex="-1" data-bind="value: interestRate">
            </div>
            <div class="calculators-inputs">
                <div class="input-group input-append">
                    <input name="interestRate" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="0" required="" data-bind="number, live: interestRate" data-parsley-min="0" data-parsley-max="30" data-parsley-validation-threshold="1" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" data-parsley-pattern="^[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$" data-parsley-maxlength="5" data-parsley-errors-container="#affordabilityCalErrorApr">
                    <span class="input-group-addon add-on">%</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="calculators-inputs-error" id="affordabilityCalErrorApr"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="calculators-form-field credit-reduction">
            <div class="calculators-labels">
                <label>Down payment<i class="label-tooltip icon-info-sign glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip"></i>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="calculators-sliders">
                <input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="20000" step="100" tabindex="-1" data-bind="value: dPayment">
            </div>
            <div class="calculators-inputs">
                <div class="input-group input-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-addon add-on">$</span>
                    <input name="downPayment" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="0" data-bind="number, live: dPayment" data-parsley-min="0" data-parsley-max="20000" data-parsley-validation-threshold="1" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" data-parsley-errors-container="#affordabilityCalErrorDown">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="calculators-inputs-error" id="affordabilityCalErrorDown"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="calculators-actions">
            <div class="calculators-buttons">
                <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

What I have now:

[image]

This is what I need:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original `table` and `table-cell` solution - http://jsfiddle.net/0jvnryhx/1/

New solution due to the updates from @ChaniLastnamé http://jsfiddle.net/8pq6thr7/

```
.input-group {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
}

.add-on {
    width: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.form-control {
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Then you can manually adjust the `width` of the input the boxes to make them fit the container (visually full width), everything needs to be fixed width though.

Answer (score 0):

Should be simple enough to do with just a calc().

```
.form-control{
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

Here is a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyzWKY)

Answer (score 0):

[Can you support flexbox?](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) If so this is your solution:

```css
.input-group {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: baseline;
  align-items: baseline;

  /* make it pretty */
  background: lightgrey;
  /* whatever width you want */
  width: 300px;
}

.input-prepend span {
  /* that width you said needed to be there */
  width: 30px;
  /* align the $ against the input */
  text-align: end;
}

.input-prepend input {
  /* use all the space */
  width: 100%;
  
  /* make the input after the $ in layout */
  -webkit-order: 2;
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group input-prepend">
  <input name="monthlyBudget" class="form-control" placeholder="0" required="" data-bind="number, live: monthlyBudget" data-parsley-min="50" data-parsley-max="5000" data-parsley-validation-threshold="1" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" data-parsley-errors-container="#affordabilityCalErrorBudget" type="text">
  <span class="input-group-addon add-on">$</span>
</div>
```

If the browsers you need do not support flexbox. There are a few options. First I really really hope you’re able to render the span **before** the input instead of after the way it is in the code you posted. You also need to ensure there are no spaces in your HTML as that will cause [this issue](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). If this HTML comes from a pre-rendered output you probably won’t have that issue.

If you can make those tweaks to the HTML this is your solution:

```css
.input-group {
  /* make it pretty */
  background: lightgrey;
  /* whatever width you want */
  width: 300px;
}

.input-prepend span {
  /* can’t set width properly while inline */
  display: inline-block;
  /* that width you said needed to be there */
  width: 30px;
  /* align the $ against the input */
  text-align: end;
}

.input-prepend input {
  /* use all the space minus the 30px from above */
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  /* change the way width is calculated */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group input-prepend"><span class="input-group-addon add-on">$</span><input name="monthlyBudget" class="form-control" placeholder="0" required="" data-bind="number, live: monthlyBudget" data-parsley-min="50" data-parsley-max="5000" data-parsley-validation-threshold="1" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" data-parsley-errors-container="#affordabilityCalErrorBudget" type="text"></div>
```

Finally if you really seriously can’t touch your markup AND you can’t support flexbox. You can do this which is a bit hacky but in the scheme of things not horrible:

```css
.input-group {
  /* make it pretty */
  background: lightgrey;
  /* whatever width you want */
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.input-group span {
  /* can’t set width properly while inline */
  display: inline-block;
  /* that width you said needed to be there */
  width: 30px;
  /* align the $ against the input */
  text-align: end;
  
  /* pull this out of flow */
  position: absolute;
  /* vertically align with input */
  top: 2px;
}

.input-group input {
  /* use all the space */
  width: 100%;
  /* allow space for $ */
  margin-left: 34px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group input-prepend">
  <input name="monthlyBudget" class="form-control" placeholder="0" required="" data-bind="number, live: monthlyBudget" data-parsley-min="50" data-parsley-max="5000" data-parsley-validation-threshold="1" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" data-parsley-errors-container="#affordabilityCalErrorBudget" type="text">
  <span class="input-group-addon add-on">$</span>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for that but I need to support IE8+

Comment: I tried the 3rd method since its the only option I can do. And this is what I get: http://i.imgur.com/meLP5WV.png Im loosing my mind over this now :S

Comment: Really difficult to see what the issue is from a screenshot but it looks like increasing the `margin-left` on the input might be what you want.

Comment: But what about the text on the right? I need them all on left side?

Comment: Looking at the HTML you posted above, for some godforsaken reason the parent elements for those have a different classname: `append` instead `prepend` which is ridiculous considering those are meant to be prepended. You need change your CSS selectors to accommodate.  I would just select with input-group instead of input-prepend. So for example you would now have: `.input-group input {}` instead of the previous .input-prepend input {}. You need to also change the selector for `span`.

Comment: Yes I did select input-group. And thats what I got as you see on the image

Comment: I’ve edited my 3rd answer above so that you can understand more clearly.